# Could not find the following Boost libraries : boost_python2 while trying to configure boost for making work pyopenpose

Tags: linux, boost, cmake, openpose

I want to build this repository :

https://github.com/FORTH-ModelBasedTracker/PyOpenPose

On Ubuntu 19.10 :

**Linux zio-Z390-AORUS-PRO 5.3.0-40-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 31 20:24:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

```
mario@zio-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/home/zio/Scrivania/src/boost# whereis python

python: /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.7-config /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.7 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.7m /usr/local/python /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

The instructions on the page says : **Inside the root folder of PyOpenpose run cmake and build with:**

```
mario@zio-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/home/zio/Scrivania/src/PyOpenPose/build# cmake ..

Install prefix is set to: /usr/local
Generating with build type: Release
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Boost version: 1.67.0
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2100 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.67.0

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_python2

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:61 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:89 (message):
  Environment variable OPENPOSE_ROOT is not set.  Please set and point to
  openpose installation folder


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

At this point I have got boot_1_67_0 and I tried to configure it modyfing the file **project-config.jam** like the following :

```
# Boost.Build Configuration
# Automatically generated by bootstrap.sh

import option ;
import feature ;

# Compiler configuration. This definition will be used unless
# you already have defined some toolsets in your user-config.jam
# file.
if ! gcc in [ feature.values <toolset> ]
{
    using gcc ;
}

project : default-build <toolset>gcc ;

# Python configuration
import python ;
if ! [ python.configured ]
{
    using python : 2.7 : /usr ;
}

path-constant ICU_PATH : /usr ;


# List of --with-<library> and --without-<library>
# options. If left empty, all libraries will be built.
# Options specified on the command line completely
# override this variable.
libraries =  ;

# These settings are equivivalent to corresponding command-line
# options.
option.set prefix : /usr/local ;
option.set exec-prefix : /usr/local ;
option.set libdir : /usr/local/lib ;
option.set includedir : /usr/local/include ;

# Boost.Build Configuration
# Automatically generated by bootstrap.sh

import option ;
import feature ;

# Compiler configuration. This definition will be used unless
# you already have defined some toolsets in your user-config.jam
# file.
if ! gcc in [ feature.values <toolset> ]
{
    using gcc ;
}

project : default-build <toolset>gcc ;

# Python configuration
import python ;
if ! [ python.configured ]
{
    using python : 2.7 : /usr ;
}

path-constant ICU_PATH : /usr ;


# List of --with-<library> and --without-<library>
# options. If left empty, all libraries will be built.
# Options specified on the command line completely
# override this variable.
libraries =  ;

# These settings are equivivalent to corresponding command-line
# options.
option.set prefix : /usr/local ;
option.set exec-prefix : /usr/local ;
option.set libdir : /usr/local/lib ;
option.set includedir : /usr/local/include ;

# Boost.Build Configuration
# Automatically generated by bootstrap.sh

import option ;
import feature ;

# Compiler configuration. This definition will be used unless
# you already have defined some toolsets in your user-config.jam
# file.
if ! gcc in [ feature.values <toolset> ]
{
    using gcc ;
}

project : default-build <toolset>gcc ;

# Python configuration
import python ;
if ! [ python.configured ]
{
    using python : 2.7 : /usr ;
}

path-constant ICU_PATH : /usr ;


# List of --with-<library> and --without-<library>
# options. If left empty, all libraries will be built.
# Options specified on the command line completely
# override this variable.
libraries =  ;

# These settings are equivivalent to corresponding command-line
# options.
option.set prefix : /usr/local ;
option.set exec-prefix : /usr/local ;
option.set libdir : /usr/local/lib ;
option.set includedir : /usr/local/include ;

#Stop on first error
option.set keep-going : false ;

using python : 3.7 : /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/bin/python3.7-config /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/lib/python3.7 /etc/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.7
```

and giving the following commands :

```
mario@zio-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/home/zio/Scrivania/src/boost_1_67_0# ./bootstrap.sh

mario@zio-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/home/zio/Scrivania/src/boost_1_67_0# b2 --libdir=/home/zio/Scrivania/src/boost_1_67_0/lib/x64 architecture=x86 address-model=64 install
```

but the error is still there :(

Comment: Did you already installed `sudo apt-get install libboost-python-dev` on your system? If you manually updated your python2/3 installations you will need to build boost yourself. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090183/changing-the-python-version-of-libboost

Comment: mario@zio-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/home/zio/Scrivania/src# apt-get install libboost-python-dev
libboost-python-dev is already at the latest installed version (1.67.0.2).

Comment: I have already tried to build boost by myself,with these commands : mario@zio-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/home/zio/Scrivania/src/PyOpenPose/build# cmake .. ; and mario@zio-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/home/zio/Scrivania/src/boost_1_67_0# b2 --libdir=/home/zio/Scrivania/src/boost_1_67_0/lib/x64 architecture=x86 address-model=64 install

Comment: this is an incomplete question : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090183/changing-the-python-version-of-libboost